# How to let user 'Enter' an answer and make editText disappear? [ANDROID STUDIO]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class game1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game1);


final Button loseStarter1;

    loseStarter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Starter1);
    loseStarter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loseStarter1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final int[] score = {0};
            Random generateG1 = new Random();
            final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(" "+loadG1);

            new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score);
                }
            }.start();

            new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    Editable answer = input.getText();
                    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (answer.equals(loadG1)){
                        score[0] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }.start();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

The idea is, I want the user to enter a value when prompted to with the editText box that comes up after the random number disappears, then I want the editTest box they can enter in to disappear after they press enter. How can I do this, with making their text box appear when the random number disappears, and have their box disappear when they enter their answer?

Much appreciated.

Note: I am new to Java dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I do not intend to use a button that the user must tap. I want them to type their answer then tap enter on their keyboard to submit their answer."

So dont use a button. Attach this listener to the editText that input will be entered into, which, in your case is `input`. Then put your processing logic in the listener.

```
input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                //your action
                Editable answer = input.getText();
                input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (answer.equals(loadG1)){
                    score[0] += 1;
                }
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

});

Comment: I do not intend to use a button that the user must tap. I want them to type their answer then tap enter on their keyboard to submit their answer.

Comment: Could you please specify which parts I replace with my own code, and how they relate to the code I provided above? Much appreciated.

Comment: see my editted answer. Please actually try the solution, and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Much appreciated, pressing enter now does get rid of the EditText bar. The issue that remains is the fact that when loadG1 is first printed, the edit textbar is shown. I specifically placed it in OnFinish so that it only appears after loadG1 has disappeared. Instead, it is shown straight from the start, How would I resolve that issue?

Comment: Please accept this answer and ask a new one with the relevant code. I don't see any onFinish method here

Comment: I was referring to the onFinish)() in my countdown timers. Marked answer as accepted, thanks again.